# VNC over SSH tunnel between Ubuntu Desktops 12.04 ¿All three 22, 5900 and 6000 ports open?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port-forwarding, vnc, tunnel

Ok, finally I got VNC over SSH tunnel working on LAN, but the objective is to use it on Internet, so I'm a little worried about the open ports the server has. Scanning the ports, I can see these ports open: 22, 5900 and 6000.

The steps I've given so far are these:

- Installation of 'vnc4server' on server.
- Edit /etc/init/vnc-server.conf so it looks like this:

  ```
  # vnc-server.conf

  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [016]

  post-start script
          su remote_user_name -c '/usr/bin/vnc4server :0 -geometry 1024x768'
  end script

  post-stop script
          su remote_user_name -c '/usr/bin/vnc4server -kill :0'
  end script

  #End of File
  ```
- Set the VNC password by executing:

  ```
  $ su remote_user_name -c 'vnc4server :0 -geometry 1024x768'
  ```
- Edit xstartup so it looks like this:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  [ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
  [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
  xsetroot -solid grey
  vncconfig -iconic &
  x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
  x-window-manager &
  gnome-session --session=gnome-classic  &
  ```
- Finally I restart the VNV server (start -vnc-server, stop -vnc-server).
- On the client side, I'm using Remmina to make the connection, with this configuration on SSH tab:

  ```
  Enable SSH tunnel <- checked
  Tunnel via loopback address <- unchecked

  SSH port: 22 (I'ts my mind to change it, but later)
  SSH Auth: Password (I know how to make it with Pub-key; I'll do it later)
  ```

Well... I want to have the server on a remote LAN, and I don't like having 5900 and 6000 ports open...
Should I? Is that the way it must be configured?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved: Obviously 5900 and 6000 can't be accesible from any IP but localhost.

Perhaps it will help someone a bit confused as me, so I'll leave the post.